# How to submit the contact form 7 data through api?

Tags: wordpress, api, contact-form-7

https://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/752
this is the link I have used to submit the contact form though POST api, the data I have passing is down below

Note: In my contact page I can submit the contact form successfully with or without login to the site. I'm using Contact Form 7 plugin

[Contact Form in Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM0nD.png)

```
{
    "text-337": "example name",
    "email-104": "example@gmail.com",
    "text-338": "testsubject",
    "textarea-339": "example message"
}
```

Getting not allowed to access response, what's the issue here?

```
{
    "code": "wpcf7_forbidden",
    "message": "You are not allowed to access the requested contact form.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution, I have change **raw** to **form-data** in postman.

https://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/[your-form-ID]/feedback

[Result from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE1cF.png)

Comment: Perfect, valid your answer to close the post

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. The response code is "rest_no_route" for `contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/a018520/feedback` and "wpcf7_forbidden" for `contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's :

http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/752/feedback

And are you sure "752" is your contact-form ID ?

Say me if it help you

Comment: yes, ID 752
here is the result I'm getting from 
/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/752/feedback
{
    "into": "#",
    "status": "validation_failed",
    "message": "One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.",
    "invalidFields": [
        {
            "into": "span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.text-337",
            "message": "The field is required.",
            "idref": "form-name"
        },
        {
            "into": "span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.email-104",
            "message": "The field is required.",
            "idref": "form-email"
}